# How to override method in installed package in django rest framework?

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-authentication

I have installed django_cognito_jwt using pip. The package has two modules backend.py and validator.py and one **init**.py file. I want to overridea method of a class SampleClass in validator.py. I created a file in my django rest app called authentication.py. Then I called the class

```
from django_cognito_jwt import SampleClass

CustomSampleClass(SampleClass):
      
     def methodA(self):
         do something
         return value
```

I used the exact same name of the parent method with the same arguments. But the call flow does not reach the extended class. Why??

Answer (score 0):

Inherit from the desired django_cognito_jwt class within your class.
In your class, override a method with the same name as the method you want to override.
And use the class you made wherever you want